# XML schema validation error template name

Tags: xml, schema

> Error - cvc-pattern-valid: value '

Comment: You need to provide more information than this. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Well yes, you're trying to validate a zero-length string against a pattern that doesn't allow zero-length strings. So how do you expect us to help?